# When we do any moral act on the basis of greed, we get merit or sin

Tags: philosophy

I am hindu. So 
My  mind  say if you Will help anyone .
 you get rewards for example  job,beautiful wife, health,
Rebirth good place and  rebirth in  healthy human beings.
So I do good act for rewards.

This is also my greed .?
This is sin?
This is good deed?

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha speaks of three sorts of kamma:
Deeds done with the intention to create the experience of pleasure,
deeds done with the intention to create the experience of pain,
and deeds done with the intention to end kamma.

Good deeds, your helpful deeds, are deeds done with the intent to create pleasureable experience. Such deeds will create pleasurable experience.
There is no denying that. Good deeds that produce pleasurable experience tend to result in attachment to the things of this world and the things of this world, being ending things, will result in pain to one who is attached to them. But there is no thing in Buddhism like 'sin'. It is a matter only of personal welfare.

In Buddhism the goal is the ending of kamma, and good deeds are kamma, so the advice for one seeking the goal is not only to eliminate bad deeds, but to eliminate good deeds as well.

Deeds that end kamma are those based on the 8-fold Way. They are intentional deeds of not-doing and letting go. For example, Samma Vaca, High Talk, speaks of training yourself to abstain from saying what is not true. Faced with a desire to get something that is thought to be obtainable only through a lie; one intentionally abstains from that lie. By that abstention from reaction to that desire, that old kamma that resulted in the desire is halted, and that potential stream of kamma that would have resulted from the lie is still-born, dead in its tracks. The whole of the 8-fold Way consists of those places and behaviors and ideas which when followed result in the ending of kamma.

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to giving, the buddha says that the expecting  a good rebirth out of giving is not the best view, but at least there is still good rebirth out of it. As usual with the buddha what matters a lot is how the mind is when giving.

He says the best view is to know that dana is part of the path.
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.049.than.html

here is a way to give 
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.037.than.html

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have good material reward, which gives you pleasure on many levels; however, your dukkha (your attachment to pleasures as one of many causes of dukkha) does not subside as intended with respect to true practitioners of the Dharma.

Answer (score 0):

See the world from this view.

1. When people born they will die someday.
2. When poison is eaten he killed no matter whether it is purposely eaten or mistakenly eaten.
3. When baby touches the flame of a candle he get burnt, no matter baby does or doesn't know it.

This is the world, it behaves in a way that it supposed to be. Sometimes we can control it (we think we can but it is not how it should be understood) sometimes we can't. 
In that world there's something called karma which explains the variations of living beings in tge world. If you do a good you will get back a good one day. If you do a bad you will get back a bad one day.

If you look more deeper;

> Imagine you take a stone from the ground and you place it on a table
>   Now what have you done? you have made change (make it unstable) to a balanced and a stable system by changing the location of a stone. Now when the system get a chance to be stable again it tries to get the stone back to they where it was. (Imagine someone accidentally hits the stone and it directly goes to the ground level)
>   You may think its gravity. Yes of course ots gravity. But what happened the system always tries to keep its stable position by using all those forces. That's the nature!

Now when we apply this to sin and good deed, by doing good or sin you are unstabling the system. When ever the system get a chance it does stable the system. If you do good you will be given good. If you do bad you will be given bad.

Now to answer your question, doing bad while doing good, your results should be the same. 
If we take some examples on this, `you may have seen very rich people who they can't enjoy the life because they are busy or they don't like to enjoy. Tha's because they have done the good but in a bad way`

So do good but do not expect rewards for that. You will get it definetly. Just try to be happy on what you did but not on what you are supposed to get..!

Comment: Great bro  last paragraph great

Comment: @BhupendraRajput, upvoting the answer would be also a good way of appreciation :) :)

Answer (score 0):

When I feel  anger.
My speech and body and mind are both rude...
Every one knowing these experience...

When I feel fear 
My speech and body and mind are  scared .

When I do any act base on greed .
My body speech and mind are ....

No experience now

Comment: Experience of greed:: pressure increases within body -can be felt easily as tension in head , voice either becomes decompressed or becomes too high or comes with a small pressure above stomach & below chest, thoughts behind thoughts runs too fast.